# tr.myClass not working without >td, how to find why

Tags: html, css

I have a table in html like:

```
var selector = $("#searchResultsArea");

$.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
selector.empty();
var html = "<table id=\"tabRoom\" style=\"width: 950px; border:none\" 
            class=\"selectable\">
            <thead><tr>
            <th class=\"ui-widget-header\">Code</th>
            <th class=\"ui-widget- header\">Alias</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
html += "<tr onclick=\"editRoom(" + optionData.Id + ");\" 
         class=\"" + (i % 2 ? "gridrow" : "gridrow_alternate") + "\">
         <td style=\"width: 50%\">" + optionData.Code + "</td>
         <td style=\"width: 50%\">" + optionData.Alias + "</td></tr></tbody></table>";
selector.append(html);
});
```

Normally, as I know this code below should work:

```
tr.myClass 
{
    background: red;
}
```

However, somehow this is not working in the project I am working on. When I do:

```
tr.myClass>td 
{
    background: red;
}
```

this is working and the background color of all columns going red. I need to find out why the code without >td is not working but I dont know where and how I should look, there are thousands lines of css codes there and I think something is preventing the code without >td working. Any advice, I would be grateful? Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for pointing syntax error, but this is just something I did while writing this question and I fixed it. the issue is something different, it should be related to why >td is necessary

EDIT2: Code updated.

Comment: It should be `tr.myClass` in order to work. CSS is case sensitive.

Comment: `tr.myClass` works just fine: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og4fuh7h/). It's probably that another style is overriding your `background`. Try inspecting the element using Developer Tools. Merhaba! :)

Comment: `<tr class="myClass">` is a typo too. It should be `<tr class=\"myClass\">` as it's in a `""` delimited string. By the way I think you should look for either `tr.myClass>td` or `tr.myClass td` in your CSS that could overwrite `tr.myClass` or even `tr td`, `td`,  `tr>td`, anything :p

Comment: Fixed the code on the question. why !important is not working if something is overwriting after?

Comment: Use your browser's dev mode to examine your `tr` element and see what is applying the final background colour.

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle.net example showing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple spelling error, `class` should be capitalized in the class name selector `myClass`.

Try this instead:

```css
tr.myClass{
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr class="myClass">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, nice catch but this is a simple mistake while writing the question here, unfortunately:( The reason is something different.

Comment: It must be something else with your CSS then...Maybe another rule over ridding this rule? Try putting `background: red !important;` instead.

Comment: Yep, I agree with u but couldnt find what is causing it. Tried !important now, was a nice try but did not work. tr.myClass{....} not working, tr.myClass>td {...} working still.

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Comment: No unfortunately :( What type of css code may cause such thing, any guess?

Answer (score 0):

Examine the following code.

```css
tr.myClass 
{
    background: red !important;
}
tr.green 
{
    background: green;
}
tr.myClass td
{
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr class="myClass green">
    <td>John</td>
    <td style="background: purple">Smith</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The order of the styles in CSS is:

- tr.myClass (!important)
- tr.green
- tr.myClass td

and we have an inline one `background: purple`.

`tr` element has two classes, `myClass` and `green`. Both modifies the background-color. Since the `.green` class is defined after the `.myClass` class, `.green` will be applied to `tr`. How do we change that, and make `.myClass` active? We use `!important`. Thus, `.green` will be ignored and `.myClass` will be applied.

But it doesn't work, does it? Background doesn't change to red. It's blue. That's something to do with the selector being more specific. `tr.myClass td` is more specific/direct than `tr.myClass`. That's why it ignores `.myClass` even though `background` uses `!important`.

Now, look at the second cell. It's purple, not blue. That's because inline styles have the top most priority.

You should look into [Specificity - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).